# Resources to learn about Windows systems exploitation

Tags: windows, penetration-test, exploit, operating-systems

I'm a beginner in penetration testing, and I'm struggling with finding decent material to learn. I used book about nmap, Metasploit, exploit writing etc..., but they contained too much information about too many OS's. I want something specific, something that can get me familiar with Windows exploitation systems, especially Windows 7.

I also noticed that security world is changing at a baffling speed, so I would like to stay in constant awareness with these changes. What are the most interesting sites/forums/social networks and such that you advice ?

Answer (score 0):

windows is a close source **OS** so, your work is hard.

> you need learn basically about windows Architecture and you need learn
>   Assembly with c/c++ language for attack.

**specially Assembly.** 
also about this sentence :

> i used book about nmap, Metasploit, exploit writing etc..., but they
>   contained too much information about too many OS's

this tools for penetration testing only is used.not for learn exploitation at kernel or system.
as you said at title :

> about **Windows systems exploitation**

if you need learn about Exploits and vulnerability's, see Submited Exploit's at something like that :
[Exploit-db](http://www.exploit-db.com/local/)

for example : [Windows 8.1](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/35811)

i hope my post is usefull for you, but with search about Architecture about your mind OS, you can learn every thing  :)
goodluck.

Comment: What do your mean by "this tools for easy exploiation is used.not for system Exploitation" ?
It is also said that Windows systems are more vulnerable to attacks then other OS's. Why do you think it's a hard task ?

Comment: no this is not hard task dude, but i think this tools at first way for learning , cant help you.(personal opinion).anyway i edit this text for eliminate misunderstanding.